# How to install mongodb connector Kafka under windows?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have installed Kafka in Windows.
Also unpacked connector files jar.

Where to specify path to these files and how to configure the connector and launch it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In connect properties file, there is `plugin.path`, which should be set to the absolute path of the parent directory of all connectors folders.

https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/managing/community.html

Comment: Where to find this file? There is no in /kafka/config. Also should I create a connector file properties?

Comment: Could you share instructions from the scratch? Please

Comment: `connect-standalone` or `connect-distributed.properties` does exist

Comment: I suggest following the examples provided by Mongo or Debezium for using their Connectors

Comment: The examples not clear , I have tried, they shows instructions under Linux

Comment: JAR files are not Linux specific. Neither are the `connect-standalone` or `connect-distributed` scripts. Have you found `plugin.path` in the property file? What error are you running into?